# If time is bigger than and lower than

Tags: php, time, timestamp, minute

I want to know how do I use php to ask if time is bigger than

08:30

and lower than

21:15

if I use :

```
<?php

if ( (date("H")>8&&date("i")>30) && (date("H")<21&&date("i")<25) ) {
echo 'This website is closed from 08:30 - 21:25. Sorry for the Inconvenience.';
exit;

}

?>
```

This is not an accurate way to say that because even if time is bigger than 8 and lower than 21 there is a minute validation here...

Comment: Why not simplify to `if ((date('Hi') > 830) && (date('Hi') < 2125))`

Comment: @Mark Baker :) Soooss Simple !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the date/time and strip of the date part. That time can be compared to other time values. In the code below, I calculate the values in seconds from midnight for the current time, 8:30 and 21:15, and then the `if` becomes quite simple:

```
define('SecondsPerDay', 86400);
define('SecondsPerHour', 3600);
define('SecondsPerMinute', 60);

$time = time () % SecondsPerDay;

$from = 8 * SecondsPerHour + 30 * SecondsPerMinute;
$to = 21 * SecondsPerHour + 15 * SecondsPerMinute;

if ($time >= $from && $time < $to) {
  echo 'This website is closed from 08:30 - 21:25. Sorry for the Inconvenience.';
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain please more about these numbers? 21*3600? 15*60? Why *3600? why *60? Looking and looking and I can't see

Comment: It's all in seconds, so 86400 seconds per day, 3600 seconds per hour, 60 seconds per minute. All calculation is talking about 1 day only, so time is kept within a 24 hour range using modulo, and 8:30 is converted to seconds by doing 8*seconds_per_hour + 30*seconds_per_minute. I'll update the code.

Comment: that's smart. I like that

Answer (score 0):

```
$startTime = '08:30';
$endTime = '21:15';
$time = new DateTime($startTime);
$time1 =  date_format($time, 'H:i'); 
$time = new DateTime($endTime);
$time2 =  date_format($time, 'H:i');
"Today is " . $current =date("H:i") . "<br>";
if ($current > $time1 && $current < $time2)
{
echo 'This website is closed from 08:30 - 21:25. Sorry for the Inconvenience.';
}else{

echo "It's open";
}
```

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)